# QGIS Composer template between projects

Tags: qgis, print-composer, template

I'm trying to create a composer template in QGIS 3.24 which can be used across multiple projects.

My font settings, however, seemingly randomly reset and default back to MS Shell dg font size 10 when using them on other projects.

This is to roll out across multiple people to maintain consistency in our map templates.

Every other part of the composer template remains the same, however.

Comment: Have you checked the font settings of the other projects?

Comment: Be careful, if the other computers do not use the same version of QGIS.

Comment: The template works between versions 3.20 and 3.28 on default installations across different project, but it will randomly reset the font and font size on a project which is quite perplexing.

Comment: You need to check that the font is installed on all the computers - I have set my templates to all use Arial Narrow for example but on computers where it isn't installed it would default back to MS Shell Dlg (or whatever the default font was). You can configure the default font used in map layouts to be something different (e.g. Arial in my case), so the backup font is not quite as ugly.